# Cordova Media Capture Android error no.3 issue

Tags: android, audio, cordova

I am currently developing a mobile application that is all about very short sound recordings and for the time sake I decided to build it with Cordova (not Phonegap). Unfortunately today I have been fighting with the actual sound recording on my Nexus 5.

I am using the Cordova media-capture plugin, The code currently running is exactly the code from their documentation.

On older device, everything runs great. On my Nexus 5 though, when I click on button to record audio, it just returns error code number 3 (No media files recorded) even without opening the audio recorder. I thought it might be problem with new Android, but on simulator it runs fine. I also thought that somehow it could be connected to that I cannot find any audio recording app on my device, so I installed one and still nothing.

Then I thought maybe I am doing something wrong, so I installed this app: https://github.com/Icenium/sample-capture and the same problem.

There has been some advice around here to update the Capture Java file, which I did and still didn't help. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no application installed, by default, to handle the intent (as explained above by others).

Try installing an application that handles that intent. For example I used this one:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brightattic.soundrecorder&hl=en

(Please note I offer no endorsement of the app other than it worked to prove that the problem was a lack of sound recorder app).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to set the targetsdk to 18 instead of 19 in androidmanifest.xml (and of course be sure to have installed api 18 in android sdk manager).

This should force the new kitkat chrome webview to operate in quirk mode and behave like the webview in jellybean.

Comment: Will try after installing older sdk. Thanks! Actually I just found out that there is a "media" plugin which I managed to make work. Also it doesn't open up a app to record the sound, but you can control it with your own events. So now I am going to be fighting with touchstart and touchend :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running `adb logcat` is useful:

```
W/System.err(22102): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
...
D/CordovaLog(22102): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 77 : Capture ERROR: {"message":"Canceled.","code":3}
```

For me the problem is that Nexus 5 (android 4.4.2) doesn't handle the Intent, i.e. doesn't seem to have a default audio recorder.
On devices which do have a default audio recorder, you might see this error if that application doesn't include a receiver for RECORD_SOUND..